# How to direct https traffic from aws ELB to gke pods in gcp cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, gcp

We are in the middle of migrating our micro services from aws to gcp cloud. Our REST api's are served via an api-gateway which internally calls the respective micro services.

So ELB rules were forwarding to a target group of api-gateway servers. Now we want to migrate this api-gateway service part by part into GCP cloud.

How can we forward an ELB rule with pattern lets say /home/* to an api-gateway cluster in gcp cloud ? We have 2 options to create on ELB rules 1. forward to target group and 2. permanent redirect. I dont think either of these will help us.

Please suggest the best way to go about solving this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look the sections APi did..

Try to make some example copy api transfer and see what the benefit 1st

Some api data change is also make some a lot mistakes..

Solution: make some new portfolio node to test 1st before changing..

Comment: Hmm.. dont forget smile anytime 